# Is there difference between a Shimano HG200, 11-36, 9 speed VS HG201, 11-36, 9 speed?

Tags: shimano, cassette

Is there difference between a Shimano HG200, 11-36, 9 speed cassette and a HG201 11-36, 9 speed cassette?

Answer (score 10):

CS-HG200 is black, CS-HG201 is silver.  Otherwise they are the same.

Comment: I found at an on-line dealer that one cost 1€ more.